# Research surrounding visualisation (inner eye)

Tags: brain, visualization

> Aphantasia is the suggested name for a condition where one does not
> possess a functioning mind's eye and cannot visualize imagery.

I have self-diagnosed aphantasia, so I might be asking a question that is obvious to everyone, but completely alien to me. In that event, I am asking for a 2-3% minority of the population that have aphantasia.

I cannot visualise faces or people at all. When I close my eyes and try to visualise the rubics cube on my desk, at my worst, I don't see anything at all and at my best, I see something like each of the two images on the right (and that's really pushing it):

[image]

How are other people able to visualise a rubics cube, in how much detail? Is there research surrounding this?

Some people state, they are able to vividly visualise faces, people, their clothing etc. If they can visualise a face, with all it's details and complexities, how are they completely unable to visualise a simple string of numbers? Because if they could, they would be able to do complex arithmetic calculations inside of their head.

Since I am not (or barely) able to visualise I would like to comprehend how other people are able to visualise anything. For example, I can easily calculate something like this in my head:

[image]

If I was able to visualise things, what's stopping me from doing this in my head, and a lot more?:

[image]

Other people can't even do "5727:3". The article on wikipedia suggests that people with aphantasia often become mathematicians or engineers, which seems counter intuitive to me, as being able to visualise would give me a great advantage in either field. I cannot wrap my mind around how someone can visualise an entire face but fail to visualise a few numbers in a grid and failing basic arithmetics.

Comment: You might not get anything here, but our sister-stack [psychology.se] might be able to help. Be sure to take their tour, read their help centre etc, and be sure to include some instances of prior research to satisfy their standard requirement for it.

Comment: The question indeed is better suited for Psych & Neurosci. However, before migrating, I need a clear question from you. I cannot make up what you want to know. Literature on aphantasia? If yes, about what aspect? Or do you need a diagnosis of some kind? If yes, please seek professional help (self-help questions are offtopic here and on Psych&Neurosci). One way to bring focus to a question is by adding prior research efforts on your side. That can help to crystallize a focused question.